# Get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error after adding a viewcontroller'view as subView to another viewcontroller's view?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access

In my application I have two view controllers.First Viewcontroller is the rootViewController of the application window. when The Button in First ViewController is clicked  I add the view of the second Viewcontroller as subView to the first one's view, there is a Button in the second ViewController's view ,My problem is that the application get crashed when I tap that Button

```
-(void)theCheckoutViewisExpandedwitPatient:(id)patient
{
    SecondViewController *sample=[[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    CGRect rect=sample.view.frame;
    rect.origin.y=30;
    rect.origin.x=305;
    [sample.view setFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:[sample view]];
}
```

Comment: `SecondViewController *sample=[[MedicationsList alloc]init];` what is this ? How can you compile the code ? Is `MedicationsList` subclass of `SecondViewController` ?

Comment: @danypata I've corrected the question

Comment: You should enable the exceptions breackpoints and check the line that is causing the crash. If you don't know how to solve the issue post the line where the crash appears. ;)

Comment: When is the app crashing, on the first button tap or on the second ?

Comment: @danypata on second (ie the added one's)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that SecondViewController is not assigned to strong variable / property, therefore it is deallocated when the method returns.

Any variable pointing to an object, inside a method (called automatic variable if I remember correctly), will be removed from the memory when the method returns. As a result, object pointed to by that variable will be released. If this object is not retained anywhere else, by for example assigning to a strong property or strong instance variable, it will be deallocated. Now, what you are doing is, you grab second view controller's view and stick it into view hierarchy of the view controller's view where this method is defined. The method returns, variable is popped off the stack, SampleViewController is not retained in any way, so it gets released. Any actions that "new" view performs, that result in a call to its view controller (the second view controller), such as button tap event notification, will end up in a crash, as that view controller is no longer in the memory.

Btw. You are simply not doing it right. Look at View Controller Containment API, if you wanna write custom containers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes problem is here. When you click on button , its try to fire method which is in `secondviewcontroller`. But before your call, secondviewcontroller will out of scope(`get dealloc`) after this method call `theCheckoutViewisExpandedwitPatient`.

We can simply say `[button->target not alive]`

Comment: How did you get to this conclusion ?. The app will crash when the `[self.view addSubview:[sample view];` is called because [sample view] is nil.

Comment: Because , button which is in xib which is assign its target , but not retain. see this method `theCheckoutViewisExpandedwitPatient`, Here where is he retain his second view controller? He just alloc viewcontroller ..

Comment: First of all, if you add a button's target from xib the method will be something like -(IBAction)nameOfTheMethod, not -(void)nameOfTheMethod. Second, the app crashes when he taps on the first button from the first view controller. Third, the question is kind of unclear and maybe both of us didn't understand it :))

Comment: No No.. You talk about `selector`. I'm telling about `target`. which like `button.target = self;` Instead it is wire up in xib.

Comment: No I think question is correct. But I don't know "Why didn't this guy  reply?" :)

Comment: hey guys I said my app get crash on tapping second button

Comment: @1211532 The second button is in second view controller? Am I right?

Comment: That means, my answer is correct. see @foFox answer, he explained briefly.

Comment: When you try to click your second view controller button which is in firstviewcontroller view hierarchy's view but it have target as secondviewcontroller which is already deallocated.  That's why it get crashed because it cann't find its target memory.